# Blender 2.49b: Loop animation between selected markers

Tags: animation

My question refers to an example .blend file supplied with the Mount and Blade: Warband trf exporter. In it, one can find the following Action Editor set-up:
[image]

Note the `WalkLoop1Start` and `WalkLoop1End` pose markers; When I play the animation from the beginning, the full 150 frames are played, following which the animation jumps to `WalkLoop1Start` and loops between those two pose markers indefinitely.

I would like to have a similar set-up, but I have been unable to find the right buttons to do such a thing. Looking at the example does not help, as creating the pose markers is not the issue; Telling the animator to loop between them, is.

Please note that I am NOT talking about the NLA Editor cyclic extrapolation functionality; this .blend file uses none.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea. I'm not sure if you realize, but 2.49 is so old many of us have completely forgotten any version specific issues. It was released around 8 years ago. If at all possible, I'd very strongly recommend using a newer version. If for some reason you can not, do not be discouraged or upset if you don't get an answer.

Comment: Why are you using 2.49? The interface and animation settings changed a lot after version 2.49. If your goal is to learn blender I would suggest you start with the current version. Getting support for that particular version might be difficult, or what you learn from this project might not apply to current versions.

Comment: The export script I use only works in 2.49b, although this isn't really an excuse as I suppose I could just as well do the animation in 2.7x, and load in to the old version exclusively for exporting (I think I can, at least). At this stage I'm simply driven by frustration that I cannot replicate such seemingly simple functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The options I was looking for were indeed trivial. Nor did the pose markers have anything to do with the looping.

On the Timeline window, select "Frame" menu, followed by "Set as Start (Shift s)". This merely means that if the animation starts before this point, it will advance normally until the end point, following which it will loop in-between the current start and end points.

One can see the start and end points in the image in the OP by noting the section of light gray in the timeline window (Which also happens to match up with the pose markers, implying that they have something to do with the looping; they don't.)